# Freelibrary using remote thread

Tags: c++, windows

In the book Windows via C/C++, Part IV , Chapter 22 - Injecting a Dll Using Remote Thread.

In the function `BOOL WINAPI EjectLibW(DWORD dwProcessId, PCWSTR pszLibFile)`, the code:

```
hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0,
        pfnThreadRtn, me.modBaseAddr, 0, NULL);
```

My Question:
Why the 5th `param` is not `me.hModule`? the `Freelibrary` `func` need a `param` of `hModule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typo, but still works because [HINSTANCEs/HMODULEs are now simply a pointer to the address where the DLL is mapped in the process's VA space](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/14/155107.aspx).

Also, please don't inject threads into arbitrary processes, it is *very* tricky to get right in the general case.